# __sync_val_compare_and_swap vs __sync_bool_compare_and_swap

Tags: c++, c, gcc, atomic, built-in

I've been thinking about the return values of these two functions.  The __sync_bool_compare_and_swap function's return value seems to have obvious benefits, i.e. I can use it to tell whether the swap operation took place.  However I can't see a good use of __sync_val_compare_and_swap's return value.

Firstly, lets have a function signature for reference (from GCC docs minus the var args):

```
type __sync_val_compare_and_swap (type *ptr, type oldval type newval);
```

The problem I see is that the return value of __sync_val_compare_and_swap is the old value of the *ptr.  To be precise, it's the value which was seen by the implementation of this function once appropriate memory barriers had been put in place.  I explicitly state this to cater for the fact that between calling __sync_val_compare_and_swap and executing instructions to enforce the memory barrier the value of *ptr could easily change.

Now, when the function returns what can I do with that return value?  There's no point trying to compare it to *ptr because *ptr can now be changed on other threads.  Likewise comparing newval and *ptr doesn't really help me either (unless I lock *ptr which probably undermines my use of atomics in the first place).

So all that's really left for me to do is ask whether the return value == oldval, which is effectively (see below for a caveat) asking whether the swap operation took place.  So I could have just used __sync_bool_compare_and_swap.

The caveat I just mentioned is that the only subtle difference I can see here is that doing so doesn't tell me whether the swap occured or not, it just tells me that at some point before the memory barrier was released *ptr had the same value as newval.  I'm considering the possibility that oldval == newval (although I'd struggle to see a way of implementing the function efficiently so that it could check these values first and not swap if they were the same so it's probably a moot point).  However I can't see a situation where knowing this difference would make a difference to me at the call site.  In fact, I can't imagine a situation where I would set oldval and newval to be equal.

My question is thus:

*Is there any use case in which using __sync_val_compare_and_swap and __sync_bool_compare_and_swap would not be equivalent, i.e. is there a situation where one provides more information than the other?*

**ASIDE**

The reason I was thinking about this was that I found an implementation of __sync_val_compare_and_swap in terms of sync_bool_compare_and_swap which has a race:

```
inline int32_t __sync_val_compare_and_swap(volatile int32_t* ptr, int32_t oldval, int32_t newval)
{
    int32_t ret = *ptr;
    (void)__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(ptr, oldval, newval);
    return ret;
}
```

The race being on the storing of *ptr in ret, as *ptr could change before __sync_bool_compare_and_swap is called.  It made me realise that I there doesn't seem to be a safe way (without extra barriers or locks) of implementing __sync_val_compare_and_swap in terms of sync_bool_compare_and_swap.  This got me thinking that the former must provide more "information" than the latter, but as per my question I don't see that it really does.

Comment: One use: the returned current value can be used for a retry. I know there are atomic increments but for illustration purpose suppose you want to implement that. You can simply call the val_compare_and_swap with oldvalue as the pre-increment and newvalue as the pos-increment. If it succeeds you are done. If not, you can retry by incrementing the returned value and calling val_compare_and_swap again. With the bool version you would need to do an extra read of the current value for retry.

Comment: You're right that the code in your "aside" is buggy/has a serious race condition. A retry loop is required to make it correct. See my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The operation provided by `__sync_val_compare_and_swap` can always be implemented in terms of `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` (and of course the other direction is obviously possible), so in terms of *power* the two are equivalent. However implementing `__sync_val_compare_and_swap` in terms of `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` is not very efficient. It looks something like:

```
for (;;) {
    bool success = __sync_bool_compare_and_swap(ptr, oldval, newval);
    if (success) return oldval;
    type tmp = *ptr;
    __sync_synchronize();
    if (tmp != oldval) return tmp;
}
```

The extra work is needed because you could observe failure of `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` but then read a new value from `*ptr` that happens to match `oldval`.

As for *why* you might prefer the `__sync_val_compare_and_swap` behavior, the value that caused failure may give you a starting point to retry the operation more efficiently or might indicate a meaningful *cause* of the failure for some operation that won't be "retried". As an example, see the code for `pthread_spin_trylock` in musl libc (for which I am the author):

http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/thread/pthread_spin_trylock.c?id=afbcac6826988d12d9a874359cab735049c17500

There `a_cas` is equivalent to `__sync_val_compare_and_swap`. In some ways this is a stupid example since it's just saving a branch or conditional move by using the old value, but there are other situations where multiple old values are possible and knowing the one that caused the operation to fail matters.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm clear on your implementation of __sync_val_compare_and_swap.  Why are you looping?  My understanding of __sync_bool_compare_and_swap is that it would try to swap only once and "failure" means oldval != *ptr, not that the function failed in some way.  As for the lines from type tmp = *ptr; onwards, it looks to me like there's a race there, but I'll wait for your answer first as it might clear something up.  Thanks re the "why" part of your answer.

Comment: @AndrewParker: Because to provide a working implementation of `__sync_val_compare_and_swap`, you **must** return a value which the pointed-to object had at some time during the operation that's not equal to the argument `oldval`. Finding such a value is impossible without looping until you find it. Imagine another concurrent thread rapidly toggling (via valid atomic swaps) the object's value between `oldval` and some otherwise-hidden value.

Comment: I see.  One final thing troubles me. *ptr could change before you can compare it with oldval, but it could change to another value which is not equal to oldval.  Thus this implementation could return a value which had no relation to why the swap was unsuccessful.  It's a pedantic point but I wonder whether it contradicts the specification of the function. To quote GCC pages: "The “val” version returns the contents of *ptr before the operation.".  This implementation wouldn't be returning the contents of *ptr **before** the op.

Comment: @AndrewParker: What counts as "before the op" is something you get to decide if you're failing (and thus not changing the pointed-to object). As long as you return some value other than `oldval` that `*ptr` had at some time during the call, and ensure the proper sequencing of all other stores/loads relative to the store that caused the value you return to be observed, you can define the moment of "the op" as the return of the function.

Comment: If on the other hand the compare-and-swap succeeds, then the moment of the operation is constrained by its visibility to other threads, etc. but then it doesn't matter because you're returning `oldval`.