# Missing sync_val_compare_and_swap_1

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, linker, llvm

I have a standalone toolchain NDK13b, api19, llvm 3.8 compiler, arm 32 bit, with libcpp (llvm C++ library)

I want to avoid depending on libgcc, so I build compiler-rt. The best version I could find (that which leaves me with the least undefined symbols) comes from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/compiler-rt/

In my link line I have:

```
-nodefaultlibs
```

to avoid linking to libgcc, and:

```
-lc++_static -lc++abi -lunwind -latomic -ldl -lm -lc -landroid -landroid_support -lclang_rt.builtins-arm -latomic
```

to link to all standard libraries.

When I try to link my program, I get the following undefined references:

> /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r13-release/external/libcxx/src/algorithm.cpp:83:
>   error: undefined reference to '__sync_val_compare_and_swap_1'
>   /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r13-release/external/libcxx/src/ios.cpp:74:
>   error: undefined reference to '__sync_val_compare_and_swap_1'
>   /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r13-release/external/libcxx/src/locale.cpp:53:
>   error: undefined reference to '__sync_val_compare_and_swap_1'
>   /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r13-release/external/libcxx/src/locale.cpp:464:
>   error: undefined reference to '__sync_val_compare_and_swap_1'

Is there any way to circumvent this, for example by defining myself the function, or by linking an extra library?

When I tried to use the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909819/sync-val-compare-and-swap-vs-sync-bool-compare-and-swap) (which is actually for `sync_val_compare_and_swap` without `_1`), I got:

> ../lib/builtins/sync_val_compare_and_swap_1.c
>   ../lib/builtins/sync_val_compare_and_swap_1.c:6:16: error: conflicting
>   types for '__sync_val_compare_and_swap_1' inline int32_t
>   __sync_val_compare_and_swap_1(volatile int32_t* ptr, int32_t oldval, int32_t newval)
>
> ```
>           ^
> ```
>
> ../lib/builtins/sync_val_compare_and_swap_1.c:6:16: note: '__sync_val_compare_and_swap_1' is a builtin with type 'char (volatile char *, char, char, ...)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was linking the libraries in

```
link_directories("${COMPILER_PATH}/../arm-linux-androideabi/lib")
```

Where effectively the varius libatomic.a, libstdc++.a etc. exist. But the correct version is apparently in the subfolder armv7-a, so it should have  been:

```
link_directories("${COMPILER_PATH}/../arm-linux-androideabi/lib/armv7-a")
```